# Does Flexbox in React Native use dp or pixel?

Tags: android, react-native

As the title mentions, I am confused about the unit of layout size values used in RN. In the [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/pixelratio.html#content), there is the code below that suggests it uses dp instead of pixel as the size unit. Here the getPixelSizeForLayoutSize() function tries to convert dp values to pixel values. However, in real applications, my components get out of screen bound when not dividing the size values (height/width, etc) using PixelRatio.get(). Would really appreciate your clarification!

```
var image = getImage({
  width: PixelRatio.getPixelSizeForLayoutSize(200),
  height: PixelRatio.getPixelSizeForLayoutSize(100),
});
<Image source={image} style={{width: 200, height: 100}} />
```

Answer (score 12):

React Native uses logical pixels (also know as "points" on iOS), as opposed to device pixels, at the JavaScript level. When working at the native level, you occasionally may need to work with device pixels by multiplying the logical pixels by the screen scale (e.g. 2x, 3x).

When you are working with images, you'll want to specify their dimensions in logical pixels. Also, React Native supports fractional pixels. When you need to specify precise layouts at the granularity of device pixels, use `1 / PixelRatio.get()`.

Comment: Thanks Ide. All my designs are now in dp (Android version of the  iOS "points" or logical pixels). Is there a way to convert dp to iOS points? I did some search but couldn't find much useful info.

Comment: I've also figured it out. In Android terms, I think Flexbox uses dp as the unit at Javascript level.

Comment: @ZJL so can you please answer my question, I can't find a solution anywhere..! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38325043/react-native-how-to-scale-font-size-to-support-many-different-resolutions-and-s

Comment: @SudoPlz I don't have much experience with fonts, so couldn't help much on your question. The Dimensions api might help.