# what dimension units are used in React Native?

Tags: react-native

When using React Native to define some styling dimensions do not have any units:

```
welcome: {
  fontSize: 20,
  margin: 10,
}
```

I assume the reason is because it's cross platform code, and iOS and Android use different units.

The [docs](https://github.com/necolas/react-native-web/blob/master/docs/guides/style.md) are not very helpful since all the examples use `rem` units and there's no mention about units anywhere.

So what units are being used for each platform?

Edit: the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33670100/does-flexbox-in-react-native-use-dp-or-pixel) doesn't say what units are being used in Android. I'm presuming it's `dp` but it isn't specified anywhere.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does Flexbox in React Native use dp or pixel?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33670100/does-flexbox-in-react-native-use-dp-or-pixel)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The units are logical pixels for iOS. See SO question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33670100/does-flexbox-in-react-native-use-dp-or-pixel), which was answered by a contributor to React Native.

For Android, the units are in [DIP](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities.html) which is kinda similar to logical points in iOS (There is a nice [write up](http://blog.fluidui.com/designing-for-mobile-101-pixels-points-and-resolutions/) on the subject). If you look at the source code [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/235b16d93287061a09c4624e612b5dc4f960ce47/ReactAndroid/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/uimanager/LayoutShadowNode.java#L24),  you'll see that they convert the supplied value `toPixelFromDIP`.

Comment: That answer talks about points in iOS, but it doesn't specify what units are being used in Android.

Comment: You're right @Pier, I've updated my answer. See if that helps :)