# How to set width and height of an Android Emulator

Tags: android, react-native

I would like to specify the width and the height on an Android emulator in order for it to emulate a real device that I have that has width `1440` height `1920`(not sure in what units of measurement, the values for width and height are printed with the following React Native code).

```
var {height, width} = Dimensions.get('window');
console.log("Width is: " + width);
console.log("Height is: " + height);
```

I have set the resolution to be `1440*1920` hoping that its width and height should be `1440` and `1920` respectively.

However, I get this:

```
Width is: 411.42857142857144
Height is: 683.4285714285714
```

So, how can I make an emulator have a specific width and height? What do I need to change in its configuration?

Answer (score 1):

The actual problem is that different dimension units are used on web and mobile, there's no px units on mobile. Check this -> [what dimension units are used in React Native?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37248400/what-dimension-units-are-used-in-react-native)

Answer (score 0):

One more link on that - the size is not not in pixels but "represent density-independent pixels" - so the emulator is configured ok.
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/height-and-width.html